# Show only text in a form

Tags: forms

I just want to show the status of an item on one AJAX call. I cannot find any form element that allows me to only output text. I don't want a textfield form, since that would allow the users to enter a value.

How do I show text only in a form created with the form API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to show only text, use [`'#markup'` form element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup), with syntax like this:

```
$form['status'] = array(
  '#markup' => '<p>' . variable_get('status', t('Off')) . '</p>',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Webform ? If you want to hide something :

- Css -> display:none
- Js -> $('#fo').hide();
- Hack the weform module

Comment: @ Drupal8ForTheWin Thank you for response,but I am already creating a custom module.